# Dynamic Variables Updated by For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, text, nlp, tibble

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
FirstVector <- c("Dog Fox Funny" 
                  , "Dog Dolphin Angry"
                  , "Cat Catfish Bored"
                  , "Fish Clam Startled"
                  , "Lion Tiger Startled"
                  , "Cat Catfish Bored"
                  )
```

I need to produce a series of word frequency tables for every two entries that look like this (in the form of data matrices):

```
Dataframe1

     angry dog dolphin fox funny
[1,]     0   1       0   1     1
[2,]     1   1       1   0     0

Dataframe2

     bored cat catfish clam fish startled
[1,]     1   1       1    0    0        0
[2,]     0   0       0    1    1        1

Dataframe3

     bored cat catfish lion startled tiger
[1,]     0   0       0    1        1     1
[2,]     1   1       1    0        0     0
```

I can create the tables using the syntax below.  However I need to save them as matrices. So from the syntax I need to create dataframe1, dataframe2, and dataframe3.

```
beginvar <- 1
endvar <- 2

SecondVector <- FirstVector[c(beginvar:endvar)]

for(i in 1:3) {

 df <- tibble(id = seq_along(SecondVector), text = SecondVector)
 a <- as.matrix.data.frame(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
 b <- colnames(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
 colnames(a) <- b 

 beginvar <- beginvar + 2
 endvar <- endvar + 2

}
```

*** My actual data set is much larger.  I am breaking it into pieces to for processing purposes ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have the `SecondVector` created inside the loop while initializing a `list` to store the output

```
beginvar <- 1
endvar <- 2

lst1 <- vector('list', 3)


for(i in 1:3) {
  SecondVector <- FirstVector[c(beginvar:endvar)]
 df <- tibble(id = seq_along(SecondVector), text = SecondVector)
 a <- as.matrix.data.frame(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
 b <- colnames(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
 colnames(a) <- b
 lst1[[i]]  <- a

 beginvar <- beginvar + 2
 endvar <- endvar + 2

}
```

-output

```
lst1
#[[1]]
#     angry dog dolphin fox funny
#[1,]     0   1       0   1     1
#[2,]     1   1       1   0     0

#[[2]]
#     bored cat catfish clam fish startled
#[1,]     1   1       1    0    0        0
#[2,]     0   0       0    1    1        1

#[[3]]
#     bored cat catfish lion startled tiger
#[1,]     0   0       0    1        1     1
#[2,]     1   1       1    0        0     0
```

---

Or use a `while` loop

```
beginvar <- 1
endvar <- 2
lst1 <- list()
flag <- TRUE
i <- 1
while(flag){
    SecondVector <- FirstVector[c(beginvar:endvar)]
    df <- tibble(id = seq_along(SecondVector), text = SecondVector)
    a <- as.matrix.data.frame(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
    b <- colnames(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
    colnames(a) <- b
    lst1[[i]] <- a
    if(endvar >= length(FirstVector)){
     flag <- FALSE
    } else 
    beginvar <- beginvar + 2
    endvar <- endvar + 2

    i <- i + 1

    }
```

---

If we need to create multiple objects in the global env

```
beginvar <- 1
endvar <- 2  
flag <- TRUE
i <- 1



while(flag){
       SecondVector <- FirstVector[c(beginvar:endvar)]
        df <- tibble(id = seq_along(SecondVector), text = SecondVector)
        a <- as.matrix.data.frame(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
        b <- colnames(table(unnest_tokens(df, word, text)))
        colnames(a) <- b
        assign(paste0('matrix', i),  a)
        if(endvar >= length(FirstVector)){
         flag <- FALSE
        } else 
        beginvar <- beginvar + 2
        endvar <- endvar + 2

        i <- i + 1

        }



matrix1
#     angry dog dolphin fox funny
#[1,]     0   1       0   1     1
#[2,]     1   1       1   0     0
matrix2
#     bored cat catfish clam fish startled
#[1,]     1   1       1    0    0        0
#[2,]     0   0       0    1    1        1
matrix3
#     bored cat catfish lion startled tiger
#[1,]     0   0       0    1        1     1
#[2,]     1   1       1    0        0     0
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a list?

Comment: @EnglishmanBob If you need to create multiple objects, use `assign` instead of storing in a `list` (not recommended though)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using a list?

Comment: @EnglishmanBob Do you need to create objects like `matrix1`, `matrix2`, etc.

Comment: Yes.  I need to create objects like matrix1, matrix2, etc.